# Do you know this formula for the scalar product in barycentric coordinates?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, matrices, discrete-geometry

I've found a formula for a scalar product in barycentric coordinates which I think is pretty cool. I hope that it's new. Is it?

Suppose that you have points $x_1,\dots,x_n$ sitting in general position in $(n-1)$ dimensional Euclidean (or Pseudo-Euclidean) space $M$. In the following we consider barycentric coordinates with respect to those points $x_1,\dots,x_n$ in $M$. (For a point $p \in M$ her barycentric coordinates are unique real numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i = p$.)

For a vector $u \in M$ a  displacement vector $\bar u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the unique vector such that:
(a) $\sum_{i=1}^n \bar u_i = 0$ and (b) $u = \sum_{i=1}^n \bar u_i x_i$.

If $u$ is given we he can find $\bar u$ by the following procedure: we fix some $p \in \mathbb{R}$, we organize the barycentric coordinates of $(p+u)$ and $p$ into vectors. Say we get $(z_1,\dots,z_n)^T$ for $(p+u)$ and $(y_1,\dots,y_n)^T$ for $p$. Then  $$\bar u  = (z_1 - y_1,\dots,z_n - y_n)^T.$$

**The formula:** suppose we have vectors $u, v \in M$. Then
\begin{equation} u \cdot v = \bar u^{T} \left(-\tfrac{1}{2}D\right)\bar v,  \label{BSP} \tag{BSP} \end{equation}
where $D$ is a distance matrix for $x_1,\dots,x_n$, in other words $D_{ij} = \Vert x_i - x_j\Vert^2$.

**Proof:** Let's denote $B(u,v) := \bar u^{T} \left(-\tfrac{1}{2}D\right)\bar v$. Fix $1 \le i \neq j \le n$. We have
$$
B(x_i - x_j, x_i - x_j) =  (e_i - e_j)^T \left(-\tfrac{1}{2}D\right)(e_i - e_j) = \Vert x_i - x_j\Vert^2.
$$
So $B$ agrees with the scalar product on the edges of the simplex $x_1,\dots,x_n$. 
Since scalar product and $B$ are both bilinear we get that they agree if $u, v \in \{x_2 - x_1, x_3 - x_1, \dots, x_n - x_1\}$, indeed
$$ 
\begin{split}
2 B(x_i - x_1, x_j - x_1) & = B\big((x_i - x_1) , (x_i - x_1)\big) +  B\big( (x_j - x_1),  (x_j - x_1)\big)\\& \qquad - B\big((x_i - x_1) - (x_j - x_1), (x_i - x_1) - (x_j - x_1)\big) \\ 
& = (x_i - x_1) \cdot (x_i - x_1)  +   (x_j - x_1) \cdot (x_j - x_1) \\
&\qquad - \big((x_i - x_1) - (x_j - x_1)\big)  \cdot  \big((x_i - x_1) - (x_j - x_1)\big) \\
& =  2(x_i - x_1) \cdot (x_j - x_1).
\end{split}
$$
Finally any $u \in M$ can be presented as a linear combination of $\{x_2 - x_1, x_3 - x_1, \dots, x_n - x_1\}$ so $B$ agrees with the scalar product everywhere. **QED**

**Similar and related results**

1. [This  paper](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/bary/bary-full.pdf) deals with a $2$-dimensional case. There is no formula for scalar product but  it has a bunch of corollaries which they prove independently: condition for perpendicularity, length of a vector, circle equation.
2. Suppose that  $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is a set of points in Euclidean (or Pseudo-Euclidean) space, $D$ is a distance matrix for $x_1,\dots,x_n$, $p = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i$ and $G$ is a Gram matrix for vectors $x_1 - p, x_2 - p, \dots, x_n - p$ then
   $$
   G = \left(I - \tfrac{1}{n}J\right)\left(-\tfrac{1}{2}D\right)\left(I - \tfrac{1}{n}J\right),
   $$
   where $J$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of all ones.
   This last formula is a key ingredient in the classical Multidimensional Scaling(MDS). This formula can be seen as $n^2$ statements, one for each element of Gram matrix. Note that displacement vector for $(x_i - p)$ in barycentric coordinates for $x_1,\dots,x_n$ equals to $(e_i -  \frac{1}{n}1_n)$, where $1_n$ is a vector of all ones. (Here we technically need $x_1,\dots,x_n$ to be in general position.) Thus one can see that those $n^2$ statements are exactly the formula $\eqref{BSP}$ for $u,v \in \{x_1 - p, x_2 - p, \dots, x_n - p\}$.
3. Suppose that $X = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is a metric space with a distance matrix $D$. $X$ allows an isometric embedding into Euclidean space iff for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\sum \lambda_i = 0$ we have
   $$\lambda^T D \lambda \le 0. \label{NEG} \tag{NEG} $$
   Those are called negative type inequalities see [Geometry of Cuts and Metrics](https://www.convexoptimization.com/TOOLS/cutbook.pdf).  Lets identify  identify points $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ with some set of points in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ which are in general position. There exists a unique Pseudo-Euclidean scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ such that it agrees with the metric given by $D$ (for example you can get it from \eqref{BSP} formula). \eqref{BSP} says that \eqref{NEG} condition is a condition that "squared length" of each vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is nonnegative.

UPD:

1. There is a [different formula](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vladimir-Volenec/publication/27187089_Metrical_relations_in_barycentric_coordinates/links/0deec53a2c6ba6156c000000/Metrical-relations-in-barycentric-coordinates.pdf) for the scalar product in $2$-dimensional case by Vladimir Volenec.
2. I've made a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.11712) based on the formula from this post. The main difference is that the preprint deals with generalized barycentric coordinates which means that points $x_1,\dots,x_n$ do not have to be in general position. But the same formula still works.